# What is the best way to store a large amount of csv files?

Tags: csv, web-applications, storage

I have a web app where users upload CSV files with their data. I want to be able to save any CSV file that is uploaded and be able to access that data in the future if I need to. Right now I am saving logs from this page to a Snowflake table. I am not sure of the most efficient way to store these files at the moment. The options I have thought of are:

1. Save them on the web server the app runs on (not ideal)
2. Convert CSVs to binary and store them within the Snowflake table with the logs
3. Upload them to an AWS S3 bucket

Comment: It all depends what you are trying to achieve. Save space, allow searching the CSV content, allow easy retrieval? Note that if all what is needed is upload download, then you can just zip the CSV files upon upload.

Comment: @Tarik The only thing I am really looking for is to upload them and download them later and make sure I do it in a way that can maximize efficiency in terms of saving space. I have access to the database and an AWS S3 bucket like I mentioned, so I wasn't sure if it was worth it to utilize those. I will have a lot CSVs (anywhere from 1k-50k lines) being uploaded and I want to save them all for historical purposes.